# Let $f(z)=\frac{z^3}{(z-\pi)^3(z+5)^2}$ and let $C$ be $|z|=3$.Then $\int_C{f(z)dz}=0$ because :

Tags: complex-analysis

Which of the following options are true?

Let $f(z)=\dfrac{z^3}{(z-\pi)^3(z+5)^2}$ and let $C$ be $|z|=3$.Then $\int_C{f(z)dz}=0$ because :

(A) the residue is $0$ at its only pole within $C$.
(B) the sum of the residues at its two poles within $C$ is $0$.
(C) $f(z)$ is analytic on and within $C$.
(D) $|f(z)|< \frac {M}{|z|^2}$ for some constant $M$.

Comment: What is your thinking about question.show some effort so that others effort do not duplicate with your one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$C$ is the correct answer here because the given fuction has poles on $\pi$ and $5$ but none of them are within and on the circle

Answer (score 1):

Consider the open disc of radius $3.1$. Since $C$ lies in this disc and $f(z)$ is analytic there (the poles are at $\pi$ and $-5$, and so lie outside the disc), we can conclude using [Cauchy's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) that the integral is zero.